# Inserting using FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, formview

I am attempting to insert an items using a basic FormView control.

I am somewhat new to C# and its controls, so bear with me.
The FormView has standard entries like:

```
ItemName
ItemPrice
ItemSize
```

It also has controls that will be hidden from the user such as:

```
ItemDateCreated
ItemDatechanged
ItemChangedBy
```

These items I am attempting to modify their values before the Insert() takes place, so I have captured the event InsertButton_Click():

```
protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btnInsert = (LinkButton)FormView1.FindControl("InsertButton");
    TextBox txtDateAdded = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("ItemDateAddedTextBox");
    TextBox txtDateChanged = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("ItemDateChangedTextBox");
    TextBox txtChangedBy = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("ItemChangedByTextBox");

    txtDateAdded.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
    txtDateChanged.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
    txtChangedBy.Text = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"].ToString();

    tblItems.Insert();
}
```

It keeps telling me that the ItemName field is NULL, and throws an error, even though I can plainly see the value is being set in the textbox.  Why is this value being thrown as NULL?  Do I need to manually create the INSERT statement before I call the Insert()?  How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your .aspx code it's hard to tell for sure, but ItemName wasn't included in the code sample you gave. It sounds like your databinding syntax might not be correct, so the value in the textbox on your page isn't getting correctly mapped to the parameter in your Insert command.

Also, what you probably want to do instead of having hidden textbox controls is tie into the `Inserting` event on your datasource. This example assumes you're using a SqlDataSource control, so change according to your specific datasource:

```
private void On_Inserting(Object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("ItemDateAddedTextBox", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")));
    ...
}
```

You attach this handler in the definition of your datasource in your .aspx page. In the design view of your webpage, click on the datasource and in the properties window, click over to the Events tab. If you double-click the Inserting event, it should create the handler for you in your codebehind, and you just fill in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks this worked.  Removed the textboxes for the dates from the Insert template in my FormView, and it worked!  thx.

Answer (score 1):

If the field values are set from system then I would recommend doing that directly in Sql [using getdate](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) and not via asp.net code.

e.g.:

```
insert into mytable (...,..., ItemDateCreated) values (...,...,getdate())
```

Comment: I have getdate() set as the default value in SQL Server, but it still threw the NULL error.  I guess my code was trying to throw NULL in there.  But I got it figured, thx!